# How to get result back from CGI(C) to the same HTML page?

Tags: html, cgi

Can I display the result which is processed in the CGI(using C) on the same html page, from where the CGI is invoked?

Regards,
MalarN

Answer (score 0):

No, HTTP does not work that way.

You would have to make a asyncronious request (using JavaScript, this is commonly known as AJAX) instead.

In a nutshell, you can spawn a background HTTP request to your CGI process, instead of posting the browser to it in the main HTTP request.

See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you give me some link with examples for the same?